# How can I use a custom data model with Deeplearning4j?

Tags: java, deep-learning, lstm, deeplearning4j

The base problem is trying to use a custom data model to create a DataSetIterator to be used in a [deeplearning4j](https://deeplearning4j.org/index.html) network.

The data model I am trying to work with is a java class that holds a bunch of doubles, created from quotes on a specific stock, such as timestamp, open, close, high, low, volume, technical indicator 1, technical indicator 2, etc.
I query an internet source, [example](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo), (also several other indicators from the same site) which provide json strings that I convert into my data model for easier access and to store in an sqlite database.

Now I have a List of these data models that I would like to use to train an LSTM network, each double being a feature. Per the Deeplearning4j documentation and several examples, the way to use training data is to use the ETL processes described [here](https://deeplearning4j.org/etl-userguide) to create a DataSetIterator which is then used by the network.

I don't see a clean way to convert my data model using any of the provided RecordReaders without first converting them to some other format, such as a CSV or other file. I would like to avoid this because it would use up a lot of resources. It seems like there would be a better way to do this simple case. Is there a better approach that I am just missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ethan!

First of all, Deeplearning4j uses ND4j as backend, so your data will have to eventually be converted into `INDArray` objects in order to be used in your model. If your trianing data is two array of doubles, `inputsArray` and `desiredOutputsArray`, you can do the following:

```
INDArray inputs = Nd4j.create(inputsArray, new int[]{numSamples, inputDim});
INDArray desiredOutputs = Nd4j.create(desiredOutputsArray, new int[]{numSamples, outputDim});
```

And then you can train your model using those vectors directly:

```
for (int epoch = 0; epoch < nEpochs; epoch++)
    model.fit(inputs, desiredOutputs);
```

Alternatively you can create a `DataSet` object and used it for training:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(inputs, desiredOutputs);
for (int epoch = 0; epoch < nEpochs; epoch++)
    model.fit(ds);
```

But creating a custom iterator is the safest approach, specially in larger sets since it gives you more control over your data and keep things organized.

In your `DataSetIterator` implementation you must pass your data and in the implementation of the `next()` method you should return a `DataSet` object comprising the next batch of your training data. It would look like this:

```
public class MyCustomIterator implements DataSetIterator {
    private INDArray inputs, desiredOutputs;
    private int itPosition = 0; // the iterator position in the set.

    public MyCustomIterator(float[] inputsArray,
                            float[] desiredOutputsArray,
                            int numSamples,
                            int inputDim,
                            int outputDim) {
        inputs = Nd4j.create(inputsArray, new int[]{numSamples, inputDim});
        desiredOutputs = Nd4j.create(desiredOutputsArray, new int[]{numSamples, outputDim});
    }

    public DataSet next(int num) {
        // get a view containing the next num samples and desired outs.
        INDArray dsInput = inputs.get(
            NDArrayIndex.interval(itPosition, itPosition + num),
            NDArrayIndex.all());
        INDArray dsDesired = desiredOutputs.get(
            NDArrayIndex.interval(itPosition, itPosition + num),
            NDArrayIndex.all());

        itPosition += num;

        return new DataSet(dsInput, dsDesired);
    }

    // implement the remaining virtual methods...

}
```

The `NDArrayIndex` methods you see above are used to access parts of a `INDArray`. Then now you can use it for training:

```
MyCustomIterator it = new MyCustomIterator(
    inputs,
    desiredOutputs,
    numSamples,
    inputDim,
    outputDim);

for (int epoch = 0; epoch < nEpochs; epoch++)
    model.fit(it);
```

[This example](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/tree/921c21bcb2f634814c76eff98728a0f31d5a2edf/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/recurrent/word2vecsentiment) will be particularly useful to you, since it implements a LSTM network and it has a custom iterator implementation (which can be a guide for implementing the remaining methods). Also, for more information on `NDArray`, [this](https://nd4j.org/userguide) is helpful. It gives detailed information on creating, modifying and accessing parts of an `NDArray`.

Answer (score 5):

deeplearning4j creator here.

You should not in any but all  *very* special setting create a data set iterator. You should be using datavec. We cover this in numerous places ranging from our data vec page to our examples:
https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/datavec/overview
https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples

Datavec is our dedicated library for doing data transformations. You create custom record readers for your use case. Deeplearning4j for legacy reasons has a few "special" iterators for certain datasets. Many of those came before datavec existed. We built datavec as a way of pre processing data.

Now you use the RecordReaderDataSetIterator, SequenceRecordReaderDataSetIterator (see our javadoc for more information) and their multi dataset equivalents.

If you do this,  you don't have to worry about masking, thread safety, or anything else that involves fast loading of data.

As an aside, I would love to know where you are getting the idea to create your own iterator, we now have it right in our readme not to do that. If there's another place you were looking that is not obvious, we would love to fix that.

Edit:
I've updated the links to the new pages. This post is very old now.
Please see the new links here:

https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/datavec/overview
https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples

Comment: I didn't mean that you create a DataSetIterator, but that you use the "ETL" processes (as per the readme) to create RecordReaders which handles doing that stuff for you. My problem was that I could not find a RecordReader that could handle my data set (the class full of doubles).

Comment: You might want to rework the [sentiment analysis example](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/recurrent/word2vecsentiment/SentimentExampleIterator.java) which still uses a custom iterator.

Comment: When I search for "datavec" in the deeplearning4j examples, I find nothing. I find very few examples of RecordReaderDataSetIterator  or SequenceRecordReaderDataSetIterator. Not a lot to go on for a newbie who's trying to figure out how they work.

Comment: Hi, you're commenting on a post that's 3 years old. I've updated the links to the relevant new pages. If you have more specific questions, could you please post them either on stackoverflow or on our official forums? We'd be happy to help you from there.